# Is there way to rewite indivdiual path in kubernetes ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

For example

```
- host: "domain.com"  
      http:  
        paths:  
          - path: /?(.*) # want to rewrite this with /$1  
            backend:  
              serviceName: RELEASE-NAME-svcname1  
              servicePort: 80  
          - path: /test/?(.*) # want to skip rewrite   
            backend:  
              serviceName: RELEASE-NAME-svcname2   
              servicePort: 80
```

Any way to handle this in a single ingress ?

Answer (score 1):

> Any way to handle this in a single ingress?

Not in a single Ingress resource, no, but it will work fine with a single ingress controller.

The reason you need to create two separate Ingress resources is so that you can apply the annotation to one but not the other; all Ingress resources across the whole cluster are unioned together, then grouped by virtual host, in the ultimate emitted nginx.conf

```yaml
...
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc-1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
    ...
    - host: "domain.com"  
      http:  
        paths:  
          - path: /?(.*) # want to rewrite this with /$1  
            backend:  
              serviceName: RELEASE-NAME-svcname1  
              servicePort: 80  
---
...
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc-2
spec:
    ...
    - host: "domain.com"  
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /test/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: RELEASE-NAME-svcname2   
              servicePort: 80
```